# Change menu positon

Tags: html, css, menu

I've built a menu for my site and I want to change its position, I used this for developing it

**HTML**:

```
<ul><li class="li-bala">تماس با ما</li><li class="li-bala">سفارش</li><li class="li-bala">درباره ما</li><li class="li-bala">محصولات</li></ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
li {
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 10px 45px 10px 45px;
      padding: 10px 45px 10px 45px;
      border: thin;
      background-color: wheat;
      margin-right:0px;
      right:0px;
 }

 ul {
       direction:rtl;
       list-style-type: none;
       position:fixed;
       margin-right:0px;
       right:0px;
 }
```

I've used right in both `<ul>` and `<li>` in my **CSS** but it doesn't work and still my menu is on the left side.

[like this img](http://s1.upload7.ir/uploads/uzJ2UtHG8pX7yDuHmAm7xCX4ppZNjG4D7CwRX5qW)

Also I have to say sorry that its not a live site, it is just for training, so I can't provide you its URL.

I have another question about my webpage winch I'll ask it in next question.

Please help me into this.

Comment: Actually where you want to put your menu ?
Link is not working!

Comment: it works on my pc it ll download file and u can open it in chrome

Comment: but i wanna have it on top of my webpage before header but i want it be fixed and with scrolling its direction change

Comment: Do you want something like this: [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/ctncr309/3) ?

Comment: not actually its a proffetional one i started html css in amonth menu im thinking about is totally diffrent it has spaces between look at this: http://upload7.ir/?p=preview&s=1&q=uzJ2UtHG8pX7yDuHmAm7xCX4ppZNjG4D7CwRX5qW&s=1

Comment: your menus are already on the right side. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use boostrap so easy!:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>My first Bootstrap website!</h1>      
    <p>This page will grow as we add more and more components from Bootstrap...</p>      
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search</a>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
      <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3"> 
      <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>                        
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix visible-lg"></div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

you got the example here:
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_case_navigation.asp
demo: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_case_navbar&stacked=h

if you dont want boostrap i did this i hope helps you:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/ctncr309/6/
```

pls tell me if this works !!